# Is there a way to write RDD rows to HDFS or S3 from inside a map transformation?

Tags: apache-spark

I'm aware that the typical way of writing RDD or Dataframe rows to HDFS or S3 is by using `saveAsTextFile` or `df.write`. However, I would like to figure out how to write individual records from inside a map transformation like this:

```
myRDD.map(row => {
  if(row.contains("something")) {
    // write record to HDFS or S3
  }
  row
}
```

I know that this can be accomplished with the following code,

```
val newRDD = myRDD.filter(row => row.contains("something"))
newRDD.saveAsTextFile("myFile")
```

but I want to continue processing the original `myRDD` after writing to HDFS and that would require caching `myRDD` and I am low on memory resources.

Answer (score 1):

> I want to continue processing the original myRDD after writing to HDFS and that would require caching myRDD and I am low on memory resources.

The above statement is not correct. You can operate on an RDD further without caching if you have low memory.

You can write inside a `map()` function using the Hadoop API, but it's not a good idea to operate terminal actions inside a `map()` function. `map()` operations should be side effect free. However you can use the `mappartition()` function.

You don't need to cache an RDD for doing subsequent operations on it. Caching helps in avoiding recomputation, but RDDs are immutable. A new RDD will be created (preserving the lineage) on each and every transformation.